# UITableView custom cell images disappear after scrolling.

Tags: objective-c, ios, gridview, uitableview

I am in the process of creating my open grid view.

I created a custom cell that looks like so:

[image]

I handle populating it like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableGalleryCustomCell *cell = (TableGalleryCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if( cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableGalleryCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (TableGalleryCustomCell*)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (countingIndex < [[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] count]) {
        cell.firstAddress.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Address];
        cell.firstPrice.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Deposit];
        if ([[[[[[self appDelegate] rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] count] != 0 ) {
            [cell.firstImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] objectAtIndex:0.0]]];
            cell.firstImage.tag = countingIndex;
        }
    }

    countingIndex++;
    if (countingIndex < [[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] count]) {
        cell.secondAddress.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Address];
        cell.secondPrice.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Deposit];
        if ([[[[[[self appDelegate] rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] count] != 0 ) {
            [cell.secondImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] objectAtIndex:0.0]]];
            cell.secondImage.tag = countingIndex;
        }
    }

    countingIndex++;
    if (countingIndex < [[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] count]) {
        cell.thirdAddress.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Address];
        cell.thirdPrice.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Deposit];
        if ([[[[[[self appDelegate] rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] count] != 0 ) {
            [cell.thirdImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] objectAtIndex:0.0]]];
            cell.thirdImage.tag = countingIndex;
        }
    }

    countingIndex++;
    if (countingIndex < [[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] count]) {
        cell.fourthAddress.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Address];
        cell.fourthPrice.text = [[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] Deposit];
        if ([[[[[[self appDelegate] rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] count] != 0 ) {
            [cell.fourthImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[[[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems] objectAtIndex:countingIndex] imageURLs] objectAtIndex:0.0]]];
            cell.fourthImage.tag = countingIndex;
        }
    }

    countingIndex++;


    return cell;
}
```

It is a bit messy but it works.....until I scroll. After the image is loaded then scrolled off the screen the image disappears.

I believe that it maybe due to the imageViews of the cells being lost?

I tried the exact same implementation but with only 1 imageView in each cell and all works great.

Any point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

I appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is because your cells are being dequeued and you are populating cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using row information other than the indexPath.row.

Maybe try something along the following lines:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray         * rssItems;
    id                rssItem;
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableGalleryCustomCell *cell = (TableGalleryCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if( cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableGalleryCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (TableGalleryCustomCell*)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    rssItems =  [[self.appDelegate rssParser] rssItems];
    if (indexPath.row < [rssItems count]) {
        rssItem = [rssItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.firstAddress.text = [rssItem Address];
        cell.firstPrice.text   = [rssItem Deposit];
        if ([[rssItem imageURLs] count] != 0 ) {
            [cell.firstImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[rssItem imageURLs] objectAtIndex:0.0]]];
            cell.firstImage.tag = indexPath.row;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you please elaborate on "populating cells in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: using row information other than the indexPath.row."? I think I'm facing same problem, and doing what you are suggesting. 10x!

Comment: As you scroll up and down the tableView, the indexPath.row will increment or decrement accordingly.  However your code only increments.  For example, when the table loads, the row of the requested cells may be 0, 1, 2, and 3.  If I scroll down two cells, then row 4 and 5 would be requested (and conversely cells 0 and 1 would be queued for later use). If I scroll back to the top again, and cells 1 and 0 would be requested and cells 5 and 4 would be queued.  In your original code with the same scenario, cells 0, 1, 2, and 3 would be loaded. Then cells 4, and 5. Finally 6 and 7.

Comment: Would giving each cell its own id be using an excessive amount of memory?

Comment: It's not that giving each cell it's own ID would use an excessive amount of memory, it's that having an individual UITableViewCell for each row would be excessive.  Image that your are displaying a table that has 2,048 rows and each custom UITableViewCell consumes 1024 bytes of memory. To allocate a cell for each row, you would consume 2MB of memory.  Now assume that the custom UITableViewCells are reused once they scroll off the screen and only 8 cells are visible on the screen at any given time with an additional 4 cells for buffering content.  The memory foot print is now only 12KB.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing my experience:

Had similar problems. I have many tables in the app, and in one of them data would randomly disappear, and eventually the entire table would go away.

The problem for me was that I was dequeueing cells, giving all of them the same "unique" id. So several tables were sharing the same id, and I believe they were conflicting and messing up the cells I was looking at.

Giving each table it's own unique identifier solved the problem for me. (dah!)

Comment: Would giving each cell cause inefficient memory usage?

Comment: Well it's each cell *type* so  it sounds like falling into paradigm.

Comment: Oded. That's very interesting. I have a similar issue. I have created a table for each letter in the alphabet on the same screen, and I now realise that I have given each table the same identifier. 
The images don't disappear immediately, but after a while, when I scroll up, all the images get lost. The text remains, but when I click on a UITableViewCell, the app crashes. How would I give each table a different identifier?

Comment: An identifier is an NSString, so just append strings I guess [NSString stringWithFormat:"LetterTableCell_%c", currentLetter]
(Must admit my ObjC is a bit rusty currently, hope the line works)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, but solved by putting the actual image loading part inside "willDisplayCell" not in "cellForRow".

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CalendarTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES; //NO; //ver3.9.4
    options.synchronous  = NO;
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
    options.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
    options.version      = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
    options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError *error, BOOL *stop, NSDictionary *dictionary) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // self.progressView.progress = progress;
            // self.progressView.hidden = (progress <= 0.0 || progress >= 1.0);
        });
    };
    cell.tag = indexPath.row; //ver3.8.3

    cell.imageRequestID = [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                                               targetSize:targetSize
                                                              contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
                                                                  options:options
                                                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                if (cell != nil) {
                                                                    if (cell.tag == indexPath.row) {
                                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                            cell.photoImageView.image = result;
                                                                            cell.timesUpdated++;
                                                                            NSLog(@"cell.photoImageView.image SUCCESS!!");
                                                                            NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
                                                                        });
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }];


}
```