# Cells become empty after scrolling. (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a problem with my tableview. When I scroll and a cell disappears from the screen it becomes blank. I have built a prototype cell in the storyboard with two labels and one imageview, it have the same identifier that I use in my code. I also have built a custom class for the customcell. Here is the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
Scientist *currentScientist = [[xmlParser data] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

cell.self.cellName.text = currentScientist.self.name;
cell.self.cellSubject.text = currentScientist.self.subject;
cell.self.cellImage.image = currentScientist.self.image;

return cell;
}
```

I don't know if you need more code to help me.

Comment: Have you also tried    static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that details the problem you are encountering. I would also recommend printing out the Scientist data to ensure an object is being fetched correctly with the objectAtIndex:indexPath.row call.

From the article I linked below, I would be willing to bet that your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is the problem. One quick way you could solve this is by giving each cell its' own unique cell identifier (Just to test out the theory). However, it looks the appropriate way to solve this is by changing up your cellForRowAtIndex method.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981366/uitableview-custom-cell-images-disappear-after-scrolling)

Comment: It didn't work to give each cell it's own identifier.
How should I change my method?

Comment: Kjuly below made a good observation:  you did not add autorelease to your resueIdentifier.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, creating a different cell identifier for each one worked just fine. I have something like:

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"identifier%i%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

The rest should remain the same.

Comment: This is not good for reusing when cells are sharing same UI but different content.

Comment: this will prevent cells from reusing

Comment: Sorry I tested what you said but it didn't work. It didn't even show the cells before I scrolled. I think thats because I already have entered the identifier in interface builder for my prototype cell.

Comment: You are right. This way the cells don't get reused. It is a good solution when working with custom cells (for example if the cells contain textFields). Also, I have missed the part with the prototype cell...