# UITableViewCells get emptied on scroll (objc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

UITableViewCells get emptied on scroll (Objective-C)

I am having a problem with UITableViewCells getting emptied as soon I a start to scroll within the table view.

I already had a look at [Cells become empty after scrolling. (Xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371300/cells-become-empty-after-scrolling-xcode) - however the problem still persists.

1) I have a popover view controller, which presents a way to log into some administration. Upon successful login (which hasn’t been implemented yet, the LOGIN button simply takes one straight to a test tableView - which should be fed from some external database later on).

2) Upon successful login, the login view inside the popover gets removed and a custom UITableViewController comes into play with its own XIB.

3) This UITableViewController uses a custom UITableViewCell - since prototype cells are not possible within this configuration.

It all works to the point where I scroll the table - and all the cells get emptied for some reason.

Here is the code run down (I leave out the obvious, eg properties and table section, etc setups):

1) customPopUpViewController(XIB ,.h, .m):

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    UITableViewController *libraryTableViewController = [[LibraryAdminTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LibraryAdminTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    libraryTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 179, libraryTableViewController.view.frame.size.width, libraryTableViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:libraryTableViewController.view];
}
```

2) LibraryAdminTableViewController (XIB ,.h, .m):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.LibraryAdminTable.delegate = self;
    self.LibraryAdminTable.dataSource = self;
    self.tblContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.tblContentList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sync Pack 1",@"Sync Pack 2",@"Sync Pack 3", nil];
    [self.LibraryAdminTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LibraryAdminTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"];   
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LibraryAdminTableViewCell *cell = [self.LibraryAdminTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString* trackList = [self.tblContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellLabel.text = trackList;
    return cell;
}
```

3) LibraryAdminTableViewCell (XIB ,.h, .m) - I gave the Identifier in the Attributes Inspector “LibraryAdminCell”:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please check if everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, there is actually a cell being returned instead of just nil?

Comment: yep, I had this one first, same problem though:

LibraryAdminTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LibraryAdminTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

Comment: Typecast like this. LibraryAdminTableViewCell *cell = (LibraryAdminTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"]; This may be the problem. Because first time the above code will initialize the cell, but second time it needs to reuse. So try with this.

Comment: What content data are you talking about?  All you set above is the label text.

Comment: Inside your delegate methods you generally should not refer to `self.LibraryAdminTable` but rather use `tableView`.

Comment: Yes, I will revert it back, but problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798516/uitableview-custom-cells-disappearing-content-after-scrolling) I had to get a strong reference to the custom UITableViewController via a property in the popup controller since the ViewController (being the DataSource for the tableView) would not be retained in memory.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are not creating a new cell, when tableview will try to dequeue a cell, and it does not get the cell, then it should create the cell to use but you are not creating any cell, so it is returning nil.Try the code below

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LibraryAdminTableViewCell *cell = (LibraryAdminTableViewCell*)[self.LibraryAdminTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"
                                                                                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[LibraryAdminTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                reuseIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    NSString* trackList = [self.tblContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellLabel.text = trackList;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: 
Return Value --
A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. **This method always returns a valid cell.**

Comment: Unfortunately I am still encountering the problem of the cells being emptied with the above code.

Comment: How many rows you are creating ? comment this line in your code    [self.LibraryAdminTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LibraryAdminTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"LibraryAdminCell"]; and try my code, and also set some background color in your cell label, and check labels are there or not after scrolling the table.